# Using ActsAsTaggableOn how do I make tags controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, acts-as-taggable-on

I have a taggable `Game` model. And now I want to make a controller to display objects by tags.

I'm able to select a tag by using `@tag = ActsAsTaggableOn::Tags.find params[:id]`. But how do I retrieve all the games associated with the tag? `@tag.games` obviously doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably don't need a TagsController.

To get what you're specifically asking for, you can use:

```
@tagged_games = Game.tagged_with :some_tag
```

If the tag is something passed into that controller action you can find it dynamically:

In routes.rb:

```
match 'games/tagged/:id' => 'games#tag', :as => :tags
```

In GamesController:

```
def tag
  @games = Game.tagged_with(params[:id])
  render :index
end
```

This would allow a user to go to /games/tagged/fps to get a listing of all games tagged as first person shooters, for example (assuming your index template is a general collection listing, anyway

Comment: Thanks. I should have checked the documentation first :) Though, I'm gonna make a separate controller for tags and define a nested route `:on => :collection`. Thanks again.